# OpenCL - adding to a single global value

Tags: opencl

I'm fighting a bug related to adding to a single global value from an OpenCL kernel.

Consider this (oversimplified) example:

```
__kernel some_kernel(__global unsigned int *ops) {
unsigned int somevalue = ...; // a non-zero value is assigned here
*ops += somevalue;
}
```

I pass in an argument initialized as zero through `clCreateBuffer` and `clEnqueueWriteBuffer`. I assumed that after adding to the value, letting the queue finish and reading it back, I'd get a non-zero value.

Then I figured this might be some weird conflict, so I tried to do an atomic operation:

```
__kernel some_kernel(__global unsigned int *ops) {
unsigned int somevalue = ...; // a non-zero value is assigned here
atomic_add(ops, somevalue);
}
```

Alas, no dice - after reading the value back to a host pointer, it's still zero. I've already verified that `somevalue` has non-zero values in kernel executions, and am at a loss.

By request, the code for creating the memory:

```
unsigned int *cpu_ops = new unsigned int;
*cpu_ops = 0;

cl_mem_flags flags = CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR;
cl_int error;
cl_mem buffer = clCreateBuffer(context, flags, sizeof(unsigned int), (void*)cpu_ops, &error);
// error code check snipped

error = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(unsigned int), (void*)cpu_ops, 0, NULL, NULL);
// error code check snipped

// snip: program setup - it checks out, no errors

cl_kernel some_kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "some_kernel", &error);
// error code check snipped

cl_int error = clSetKernelArg(some_kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &buffer);
// error code check snipped

//global_work_size and local_work_size set elsewhere
cl_int error = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, some_kernel, 1, NULL, &global_work_size, &local_work_size, 0, NULL, NULL);
// error code check snipped

clFinish(queue);

cl_int error = clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(unsigned int), (void*)cpu_ops, 0, NULL, NULL);
// error code check snipped

// at this point, cpu_ops still has it's initial value (whatever that value might have been set to)'
```

I've skipped the error checking code since it does not error out. I'm actually using a bunch of custom helper functions for sending and receiving data, setting up the platform and context, compiling the program and so on, so the above is constructed of the bodies of the appropriate helpers with the parameters' names changed to make sense.

I'm fairly sure that this is a slip-up or lack of understanding on my part, but desperately need input on this.

Comment: COuld you post your code for: Creating the memory zone, reading and writing the memory zone, and running the kernel?
It is definitely not a problem of the piece of code you posted, but a problem elesewhere.

Comment: There you go. As I've explained, I use a couple of helper functions, but they work otherwise - other data is sent, changed and received properly using them, just this one unsigned int* won't behave.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I was confused about my memory handles - just a stupid error. The code is probably fine.